# Disabling hint popup

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, popup-menu

Whenever my cursor is over a function for a few seconds, this hint for the function pops up. Doesn't go away by hitting Esc and I need to move my cursor to get rid of it.

No other plugins except YouCompleteMe, if that's relevant.
How should I disable it?[image: vim-popup]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let g:ycm_auto_hover=''
```

This disables the popup.